# Understanding class_eval and instance_eval?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused as to when I should be using `instance_eval` and `class eval`.

I should or shouldn't use them?

Answer with **simple examples** on how to use them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I strongly recommend "Metaprogramming Ruby 2" by Paolo Perotta - it would answer these question in depth (along with many related ones that you didn't ask yet :)) and in general would give you a solid understanding of the Ruby object model (you _really must_ understand the latter to work with Ruby, and there is way more here than the difference between numerous `eval`-like methods).

Answer (score 3):

The `class_eval` and `instance_eval` are both used to reopen an object and define additional behaviour.

They follows the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

### class_eval

`class_eval` is used to define additional behaviour in the context of a class.

Let's use the following `Person` class:

```rb
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

Person.class_eval do
  def say_hello
    puts "Hello! I'm #{@name}"
  end
end

j = Person.new "John"
j.say_hello # Hello! I'm John

r = Person.new "Robert"
r.say_hello # Hello! I'm Robert
```

Both `j` and `p` can use a new method called `say_hello` that wasn't defined in the definition of the class `Person`, but on an extension of it.

### instance_eval

`instance_eval` is used to define additional behavior in the context of a receiving object.

The previous example could be rewritten as:

```rb
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

j = Person.new "John"

j.instance_eval do
  def say_hello
    puts "Hello! I'm #{@name}"
  end
end

j.say_hello # Hello! I'm John
```

Since we used `instance_eval` on `j`, only the behavior of `j` has been redefined, in fact we can't use `say_hello` on another instance:

```rb
r = Person.new "Robert"
r.say_hello # undefined method `say_hello' for #<Person:0x00007fac43c15b28 @name="Robert"> (NoMethodError)
```

This is the opposite of `class_eval`.

### Summary

- `class_eval` allows you to open and redefine the behavior of a class in order to extend all instances of the class
- `instance_eval` allows you to open and redefine the behavior of just an instance of a class

### You should or shouldn't use them?

I'm of the idea that you shouldn't use them, because this can lead to code fragmentation.

But you have to use them when you want to add behavior on third parties code or when you want to add behavior dynamically.

Comment: _"They follows the open/closed principle"_ – they obviously allow a class / object to be opened, but what about the "closed for modification" part?

Comment: @Stefan in order to extend the behavior you don't need to source code of a class. The source code is then "closed".

Comment: @Stefan, I've always been dissatisfied with the concept of "opening" a class or another object, as (to my knowledge) there is no mention of that in the Ruby documentation. We may share a general idea of what is meant by "opening" but I would prefer a more precise statement of the procedure.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the docs for [Modules](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html) use the term "open" / "reopen" several times.

Comment: @Nullndr I find statements like "class_eval allows you to open and redefine the behavior of a class in order to extend all instances of the class" a bit misleading. One _can_ (re)define the receiver's behavior using these methods, but this is not always the case. The receiver might be used as just a _blank slate sandbox_, as a throw-away execution context for some dynamic code (simply to isolate the dynamic code from the rest of the app and reduce the blast radius when things go wrong)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov right, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Stefan, I’m not surprised that the terms “open” and “reopen” (especially for a class) appear in Ruby docs, but they are used in the absence of a definition of what they mean. If `x` is an object is it too much to ask for a Ruby doc that defines precisely what “open `x`“ means? Alternatively, do we need to say “open `x`“?

Comment: both instance_eval and class_eval are methods used in metaprogramming and metaprogramming is an anti-paradigm, if you want to follow SOLID principles, do not use metaprogramming as it breaks them. Metaprogramming is very powerful if you know what you are doing, otherwise use another way like extend or include....

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassName.instance_eval to define a class method (one associated with the class object but not visible to instances).
Use ClassName.class_eval to define an instance method (one that applies to all of the instances of ClassName).

Answer (score 0):

Source: [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/)

[instance_eval](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/67-instance-eval)

> One of the major differences between eval and instance_eval is that
> with instance_eval you have the choice of explicitly handling the
> context of self. As instance_eval is a method on Object it is scoped
> by the object you specify.

[class_eval](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/68-class-eval)

> class_eval is much simpler than instance_eval which works on
> metaclasses (or the singleton object). It works on the class as if you
> were opening it in a text editor and adding new state or behaviour to
> it.